# Which HTTP code has higher priority: 403 or 415?

Tags: http, http-request, http-response

Let's consider the following scenario. I need to access a resource hosted on server X. I want to get this resource in a Y format, so along with my request I send the `Accept: Y` header. Unfortunately X does not support Y and I'm not not allowed to access the resource on X as well. I've included valid `Authorization` header.

How should X reply? With a `415` - telling me that it cannot talk to me in a requested format or `403` (with some body that I probably cannot read because the body parser I use supports only `Y` format).

Comment: I'd say 403 because if you are not allowed access to a resource, you shouldn't be able to query what formats are supported.

Comment: I generally follow https://www.codetinkerer.com/2015/12/04/choosing-an-http-status-code.html

Answer (score 5):

From a security viewpoint, you want to disclose as little information as possible to an attacker.

By responding with a 415 code until they hit a supported format and sending a 403 then, you are giving an attacker a mechanism to figure out which formats are supported.

If you always reply with a 403, then an attacker can't tell if there are additional reasons why the request might fail, such as an unsupported format.

Comment: Ok, and from HTTP point of view?

Comment: @Opal, to my knowledge, HTTP does not care.

Comment: That's why I'm asking. Because I think that HTTP does care. I have no idea why today we use the protocol and disobey its rules.

Comment: @Opal, I checked the HTTP specification and it doesn't mention a priority order of response codes. It does not even acknowledge that a server might have to choose between several appropriate codes.

Comment: Could you please point me to the relevant part?

Comment: @Opal Why do you think HTTP does care?  What makes you think that is the case?

Comment: @Opal, it is kinda hard to give a reference to something that doesn't exist. The closest I can give you is the [section on status codes](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6).

Comment: @Opal I would expect that when you are handling a request then authorization should be the _first_ thing you check, at which point you should return an error instead of carrying on anyway (just to see if you get the second error at all?).